# Graphql Schema doku displays Input type automatically with Input

Tags: graphql-spqr

I have added leangen/graphql-spqr as described in the readme.
Before we had a custom implementation of graphql types like in customtype.types.gql.

After implementation, everything works fine, except the type which are called e.g. OperatorInput, are named in the autogenerated graphql doc like "OperatorInputInput".
I tried to Change it like this in the declaration:

```
@GraphQLArgument(name = "OperatorInput", description = "Required fields for Operator") OperatorInput operator
```

But it wasn't applied.
Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is intended. Keep in mind that in GraphQL's type system, input and output types are strictly different. Let's say you have this in Java:

```
public Book saveBook(Book in) {...}
```

The `Book` that is the return type and the `Book` that is the argument type are 2 different types in GraphQL, and must have unique names. So `Input` is added automatically to make the names unique.

If you're 100% sure you want to override this, register a custom `TypeInfoGenerator` via `GraphQLSchemaGenerator#withTypeInfoGenerator`.  You can inherit from `DefaultTypeInfoGenerator` and override `generateInputTypeName`. BUT! Do pay attention that if you end up producing the **same name for 2 different types, all hell breaks loose**. So maybe only drop the suffix `Input` if the classname already ends with `Input` and never ever use such classes for output.

Btw `@GraphQLArgument` sets the name of the argument, not the name of *the type* of the argument.

Comment: @kaqqaio thank you so much. This makes sense!

Comment: For me it does not make sense at all. I don't really understand why the framework changes any naming convention for me. Right now I have a situation when I'm rewriting an old backend created in Spring Boot and because of this I can't keep the same schema structure. I'm sorry but in my opinion this is a nonsense to make it a default behavior.

Comment: Another point is: lets say I have this mentioned Book DTO/entity or however we will call it - then I will need to have the same name for input and output: Book, which makes it very invoventient inconvenient to use in java code as I will need to do qualified name for one of them :<